# Do multiple @Transactions cause multiple database locks in Postgres?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions

I have a @Transactional Service class EventsService and a function that deletes some events according to their state. The implementation looks like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public class EventsService {

  @Autowired private EventsRepository eventsRepository;
  
  public int deleteSentEvents() {
    String state = "SENT";
    int deletionLimit = 10000;
    Pageable page = Pageable.ofSize(1000);
    Page<Events> eventsPage = null;
    do {
      eventsPage =
          eventsRepository.findEventsByState(state, page); eventsRepository.deleteInBatch(eventsPage.getContent().stream().map(Events::getId).toList());
      deletedTotal += eventsPage.getNumberOfElements();
    } while (eventsPage.hasNext() && deletedTotal < deletionLimit);
    return deletedTotal;
  }
```

I want to move the deletion part outside of this function and have multiple smaller transactions created for each page, in order not to lock all the rows at once for bigger time. So, I changed the code like this:

```
 public int deleteSentEvents() {
    String state = "SENT";
    int deletionLimit = 10000;
    Pageable page = Pageable.ofSize(1000);
    Page<Events> eventsPage = null;
    do {
      eventsPage =
          eventsRepository.findEventsByState(state, page);
      deleteBatch(eventsPage);
      deletedTotal += eventsPage.getNumberOfElements();
    } while (eventsPage.hasNext() && deletedTotal < deletionLimit);
    return deletedTotal;
  }
  
 @Transactional("transactionManager")
  public void deleteBatch(Page<Events> eventsPage) { eventsRepository.deleteInBatch(eventsPage.getContent().stream().map(Events::getId).toList());
  }
```

Is there a way to verify that this change creates multiple smaller locks to the database, and multiple transactions as well? I am using postgreSQL and tried to query the pg_catalog.pg_locks table, but that didn't help.

Comment: The deletBatch call inside the deleteSendEvents will definitely NOT create a new Transaktion because there is no way for the class proxy to intercept this call. As for testing you could debug it and check if every result you except is already in the database. In these cases, I find using the TransactionTemplate - the annotations uses that class as well - more concise

Comment: @Loop in simple terms, I can understand that this will not create new Transaction, since the call comes from the same class with the same transaction manager. Does that mean that it will not create multiple locks to the database as well?

Comment: It won't. And if you need multiple Transactions, you should use the propagation level "REQUIRES_NEW" or something similar. The default behavior of the transactional annotation will either use the existing transaction from the calling thread or create a new one if there is no active transaction available.